# Read the first mail in the inbox, save subject content as a text file using pop3client

Tags: vb.net, email, pop3

Am facing a problem while **saving the mail as a text file** through **vb.net**. i had done the following code as per my task:-

```
public sub rearmail()
 Dim pop3Client As Pop3Client
            If (Session("Pop3Client") Is Nothing) Then
                pop3Client = New Pop3Client
                pop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, True)
                pop3Client.Authenticate("mymail@gmail.com", "password")
                Session("Pop3Client") = pop3Client
            Else
                pop3Client = CType(Session("Pop3Client"), Pop3Client)
            End If 'connect to the inbox with username and pass word authentication
        Dim message As Message = pop3Client.GetMessage(0)
        dim frm as string ' to store from address
        dim subj as string ' to store the subject
        dim mdate as date ' to store the date and time
        frm=message.Headers.From.Address
        subj= message.Headers.Subject
        mdate=message.Headers.DateSent
    '**** no i need to read the mail message and save it as a notepad file ****
    end sub
```

i had tried a lot to read the mail using :-

```
 Dim message As Message = pop3Client.GetMessage(0)
```

as follows:-

```
Dim str As MailMessageEventArgs
dim strmsg as string 
strmsg=str..Message.Body.ToString 'error null error exception at run time
strmsg=message.MessagePart.Body  ' nothing will return
```

like wise i do a lot with the message object but i fails to achieve the goal, i hope that the experts in this community can help me to overcome the problem,
thanks in advance.....♥

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the one who make a try to solve the problem, i got the solution now i wish to share it with you. here is the code segment to read the mail body content;-

```
 Dim messagePart As MessagePart = message.MessagePart.MessageParts(0)
 MsgBox(messagePart.BodyEncoding.GetString(messagePart.Body))
```